# Value check in a setter

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to implement a value validation in a es6 class property setter?
Stupid attempt failed with `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` as expected:

```
class Something {
    constructor() {
        this.maxRange = 5;
        this.minRange = 1;
        this.selectedRange = 3;
    }
    set selectedRange(value) {
        if (value <= this.maxRange && value >= this.minRange) {
            this.selectedRange = value;
        }
    }
}
```

But what would be a proper way? Is it possible to do at all in a setter? (Without using an additional method like `setProp` or `setRange`)

Comment: Please post the full code

Comment: Of course you can do that checking with the setter function. Check this blog post https://robertnyman.com/javascript/javascript-getters-setters.html And what's the point of using ES6 classes anyway? This is JS use either Object Create or Function Constructors for god's sake.

Comment: Isn't it impossible to mix setters with normal property-names? You should *always* define a getter as well AFAIK.

Comment: @Redu _"And what's the point of using ES6 classes anyway?"_ Post a question if you want to know it ... There's no need to be rude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know (feel free to correct me), you cannot mix setters (or getters) with regular values. The regular value will just be overridden.

[Getters and setters are a part of accessor descriptors and regular values are a part of data descriptors.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

You need to use both a setter and a getter, and define an internal property (for example with an underscore `_`) which is fetched by the getter and wrote to by the setter.

```
class Something {
    constructor() {
        this.maxRange = 5;
        this.minRange = 1;
        this._selectedRange = 3;
    }
    get selectedRange() {
        return this._selectedRange;
    }
    set selectedRange(value) {
        if (value <= this.maxRange && value >= this.minRange) {
            this._selectedRange = value;
        }
    }
}
```

You could even make the internal property non-enumerable, so it doesn't show up in a loop:

```
class Something {
    constructor() {
        this.maxRange = 5;
        this.minRange = 1;
        Object.defineProperty(this, '_selectedRange', {
            value: 3,
            configurable: true,
            writable: true,
            enumerable: false
        });
    }
    get selectedRange() {
        return this._selectedRange;
    }
    set selectedRange(value) {
        if (value <= this.maxRange && value >= this.minRange) {
            this._selectedRange = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this answered your question, you can mark it as correct using the green checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should understand that set is always called when you set the value of selectedRange. So you should not set the value of selectedRange inside 'set' function or else it will make an infinite loop causing Maximum call stack size exceeded error.
so do it like

```
class Something {
    constructor() {
        this.maxRange = 5;
        this.minRange = 1;
        this.selectedRange = 3;
    }
    set selectedRange(value) {
        if (value <= this.maxRange && value >= this.minRange) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```